Deserialising json with JSON.NET , unable to find the right class format
I receive a Json file. Now the other company change the Json and I have to find the right format for my class in C.Net and I'm not able to do so.
My Json looks like :
{
 {"xxx": [
 "d6952cb5c",
 "8587d4",
 "96b4d",
 "622201a",
 "55e0d455"
 ],
 "yyy": [
 "28f054091d"
 ],
 "zzz": []
}  

The thing is, I don't know the name of the field I'm going to receive. So I'm not able to create a class with the correct field replacing xxx, yyy and zzz. I can receive more than 300 of these.
Normally I had create my class like this :
 public class Root
 {
    public List<string> xxx { get; set; }
    public List<string> yyy { get; set; }
    public List<object> zzz { get; set; }
 }

Someone has an idea on How I can create the right class, Or any other way to have my data in an object or a dictionary to read them separately ?
thanks

Parse the json as a dynamic type and access members by string name. There are many code samples for this.

What are you going to do with deserialized data? Maybe you don't need deserialize, rather extract certain piece of data manually?

I cannot access members by string name, I DON'T KNOW the name of what I will receive.

You may want to familiarize yourself with these types (depending on which package you prefer for handling JSON): Newtonsoft.Json.JObject, System.Text.Json.JsonObject and potentially with the concept of C# dynamic.

It would be nice to know your goal -- what exactly you need to do with the JSON text data that you receive?

I need to access every string[] to see the data inside and I need to link with the "header". So for xxx (don't know the name) I need to know every string inside the list. And so on. On my Side after, when I will have the xxx I will be able to link with what I have in my database.

So if xxx is "Account 1245" I will be able to find what it is in my database. the the list is for example a list of people that use this account. yyy can be "Car 45" and the list is the user that use the car #45. But Like I said originally I don't know what will be the header.

I don't know because accounting can add 100 new fields. And if I miss one, I will add it in my database, so I can't create a class with a known name. I'm just asking how I create a class that will work with the data I receive or send it to another component that I can receive element by element. Thanks. It seems no one get this problem before with this kind of Json !!!

@Itallmakescents. Maybe Software development is more than just computer programming. But on the other side, you need to adjust to your client problem. They have 2 systems and one is very old. They gives me the file and on my side I need to find a solution, so your right, it's not just computer programming... it's a way to don't need the ask my client adjust to me, but me I need to be flexible to make it work!! To answer your question: I don't know because they gives me a file to let me know which ones are knew and this file is the Json! Anyway, someone answer correctly, and I gives my solution

The easiest way for this specific example is to use Dictionary<string, string[]> to deserialize object:
string json = """
{
    "xxx": [
        "d6952cb5c",
        "8587d4",
        "96b4d",
        "622201a",
        "55e0d455"
    ],
    "yyy": [
        "28f054091d"
    ],
    "zzz": []
}
""";

var document = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string[]>>(json);
foreach(string key in document.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine(key);
    foreach (string value in document[key])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + value);
    }
}

You will get this output:
xxx
    d6952cb5c
    8587d4
    96b4d
    622201a
    55e0d455
yyy
    28f054091d
zzz


Thanks for your solution. I try it, but I don't use System.Text.Json, I use NewtonJson. But you answer my question. Thanks and thanks again. So, I try on my side and found another solution. So I will write it in another commentary. Maybe tour solution will work for someone else who use System.Text.Json.

Finally working on my side, with some other solutions, I found somethig that works. Here's the code help with another stack overflow.
            dynamic parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(MyJSON);
            var jObj = (JObject)parsed;

            foreach (JToken token in jObj.Children())
            {
                if (token is JProperty)
                {
                    var prop = token as JProperty;
                    Console.WriteLine("hello {0}={1}", prop.Name, prop.Value);
                }
            }

Find the solution with another stackoverflow here:
dynamic JContainer (JSON.NET) & Iterate over properties at runtime
